# lambda contains in array

Tags: asp.net, arrays, datagridview, lambda

My array `A` may be returns array of `age` likes

```
int [] A = {11,12,13}  or
int [] A = {14,15}     or   
int [] A = {11,14}
```

My `Person` table has column likes

```
ID    Name       Age
---------------------
1     John       12     
2     Michael    15
3     Tom        13
4     Owen       14
```

How can I get row from this table depend on my array's values using lambda ?

```
myASPGridView.DataSource = DBContext.Persons.Where(.....);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like that:

```
int [] A = {11,12,13};
myASPGridView.DataSource = DBContext.Persons.Where(p => A.Contains(p.Age));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
x => A.Contains(x.Age)
```

x denotes the input (in this case, your database row) and the function returns true where the array A contains x.Age.